# What is the best practice to request an eclipse restart from plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an eclipse plugin. One of my feature needs to restart eclipse itself. I'm trying with the `IWorkench.restart()` method, but I got exceptions during restart.

Is there any best practice for this particular problem?

Comment: IWorkbench.restart is correct. What exceptions? What are you doing that makes you want to restart.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've got NullPointerExceptions on dialogs maybe because of unexpected restart(`org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.close`). I need to restart when the user changes the database, in the plugin.

Comment: Using `Display.asyncExec` to run the restart after the dialog closes might help.